# Transform a df into individual observations

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to transform a df from a "counting" approach (number of cases) to a "individual observations" approach.

Example:

```
df <- dplyr::tibble(
  city = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), 
  sex = c(1,0,1,0,1,0),
  age = c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
  cases = c(2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

Expected result

```
df <- dplyr::tibble(
  city = c("a","a","a","a","a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), 
  sex = c(1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0),
  age = c(1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uncount()` from `tidyr` can do that for you.

```r
df |> tidyr::uncount(cases)
```